# Ruby on Rails - How to Save/Show User's Total Savings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that tracks how much a user saves by not buying cigarettes that day. It has a User model which stores user data and a Pack model which stores how many packs the user buys each day. I need the app to store how much the user has saved in total so far, for which there will be a simple mathematical function. For example:

User Table

```
name: Benjamin
etc.
price: 6 EUR
daily_packs: 2
```

Packs Table

```
date: 1-2-2014
amount: 1
```

---

The user then needs to be displayed how much money they've saved So far, I've come up with the following:

```
@packs = Pack.all.sum(&:amount) * User.price
```

Then:

```
@saved = User.packs.count * User.price
```

Finally, I need to subtract @packs from @saved. However, I don't fully understand how to implement this. I've googled this quite extensively, but still can't find any information on the topic. How do I implement this code above (in the model or controller, etc.?)? I'm a bit new to Rails (as I'm sure is obvious at this point), so don't hesitate on details :P

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class User you'll have a method let's say "how_much_was_saved"

```
def how_much_was_saved
 amount = self.packs.sum(&:amount)
 amount * self.price
end
```

So if you have a User instance you just have to call user.how_much_was_saved

Your user model has to have a relation many to many with packs (has_many :packs)

In your controller just get the user you want and call @saved = user.how_much_was_saved and the variable @saved will be available in your view.